# How to show all tooltip Text where line series circle bullets intersect Amcharts 4?

Tags: amcharts4

I am using a Amcharts4 Line series with valueX and valueY instead of categoryX.
Currently I am able to see the tooltip on a hover of bullet/bubble but I also want to see the tooltip   of all bullets if they are intersecting and overlapping with each other.
It shows the tooltip if i hover on a single bullet/bubble but if you see the red and green line intersecting each other, it shows the tooltip of green bullet/bubble only, not the other which is hidden at its back.

[Click here to see Line Series graph with ValueX and ValueY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLton.png)

This is my code where I am having 3 series and setup a tooltip for each bullet :

```
let series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series1.cursorTooltipEnabled = true;
        series1.showTooltipOn = 'hover';
        series1.dataFields.valueY = "compressorCap";
        // series1.dataFields.categoryX = "evapDegC";   // If X-Axis is Category Axis
        series1.dataFields.valueX = "evapDegC";         // If X-Axis is Value Axis
        series1.name = "Compressor capacity";
        let series1toolTip = series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series1toolTip.tooltipText = "{name} in {valueX}°C => {valueY}";
        series1.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
        series1.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#b9a9e6");
        series1.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";
        series1.visible = false;
        series1.stroke = am4core.color("#b9a9e6");

        let series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series2.cursorTooltipEnabled = true;
        series2.showTooltipOn = 'hover';
        series2.dataFields.valueY = "evapCoilCap";
        // series2.dataFields.categoryX = "evapDegC";      // If X-Axis is Category Axis
        series2.dataFields.valueX = "evapDegC";         // If X-Axis is Value Axis
        series2.name = 'Evaporator coil capacity';
        let series2toolTip = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series2toolTip.tooltipText = "{name} in {valueX}°C => {valueY}";
        series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
        series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("red");
        series2.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";
        series2.stroke = am4core.color("red");

        let series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series3.cursorTooltipEnabled = true;
        series3.showTooltipOn = 'hover';
        series3.dataFields.valueY = "evapCoilSensibleCap";
        // series3.dataFields.categoryX = "evapDegC";      // If X-Axis is Category Axis
        series3.dataFields.valueX = "evapDegC";      // If X-Axis is Value Axis
        series3.name = 'Evaporator sensible cooling capacity ';
        let series3toolTip = series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series3toolTip.tooltipText = "{name} in {valueX}°C => {valueY}";
        series3.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
        series3.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#13bb37");
        series3.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";
        series3.stroke = am4core.color("#13bb37");

        // Add chart cursor
        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display multiple tooltips, you need to set `tooltipText` directly on series, not on a bullet.

```
series.tooltipText = "{name} in {valueX}°C => {valueY}";
```

That's the first step, though. Since you are using all-`ValueAxis` scenario, you will also need to apply a workaround as stated in [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/multiple-cursor-tooltips-on-scatter-chart/).

```
am4charts.ValueAxis.prototype.getSeriesDataItem = function(series, position) {
  var key = this.axisFieldName + this.axisLetter;
  var value = this.positionToValue(position);
  var dataItem = series.dataItems.getIndex(series.dataItems.findClosestIndex(value, function(x) {
    return x[key] ? x[key] : undefined;
  }, "any"));
  return dataItem;
}
```

This will enable multi-cursors across all charts.

Or if you want to enable for just for a single axis:

```
valueAxisX.getSeriesDataItem = function(series, position) {
  var key = this.axisFieldName + this.axisLetter;
  var value = this.positionToValue(position);
  var dataItem = series.dataItems.getIndex(series.dataItems.findClosestIndex(value, function(x) {
    return x[key] ? x[key] : undefined;
  }, "any"));
  return dataItem;
}
```

If you don't want to show all tooltips for all the series all the time, you can set cursor's [`maxTooltipDistance`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/#Limiting_number_of_series_tooltips) to a small number so that multiple tooltips are shown only if target items are closely packged together, e.g.:

```
chart.cursor.maxTooltipDistance = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and support mate. As you can see I have used valueX instead of categoryX, therefore tooltip is not working on series. Initially I had done the same but it didn't worked that's why I applied tooltip on bullets and it works well. My only concern is, if you see the image, where bullets override each other, on hover its showing only the upper bullet's tooltip and not the one which is hidden behind it. Please help ASAP.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sorry didn't register the all-ValueAxis scenario. Updating my answer as we speak.